# Double integral, and change of variables

Tags: calculus, integration

I have problem to intrgrate over $D$ a parallelogram restricted by $(-1,-1)$, $(-4,0)$, $(-7,5)$ and $(-10,6)$.

This is my solution, which is wrong.  Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Comment: please type your solution here

Comment: What is the correct answer supposed to be? Off by a factor 2?

Comment: Your Jacobian seems wrong. If I well understand your calculation the correct value should be $3/16$.

Comment: Thank you, i was off by the factor 2.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXY3p.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

You have a mistake in the change of coordinates.

The correct values are:
$$
\begin{cases}
x=\frac{3}{4}u-\frac{1}{2}v\\
y=-\frac{1}{4}u+\frac{1}{2}v
\end{cases}
$$
so the Jacobian is $J=\frac{1}{4}$,
and we have
$$
\int_{-4}^{8}\int_{-8}^{-4}\frac{1}{4}u(-v-1)du dv
$$